# issue with bootstrap basic template

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, respond.js

[I used the basic Bootstrap template from the below official link](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#template)

I saved this as html file and when I run the html file in Internet explorer 8 
, the browser goes in debugging mode

[image]

How do i fix this, the issue is probably because of respond.min.js file present in bootstrap

Comment: "Due to security restrictions, some browsers may not allow Respond.js to work on file:// urls (because it uses xmlHttpRequest). Run it on a web server."

Comment: thank you for the info , im running the files in my localhost and it works normal